# How to cast a sql column same as of another column in sparksql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
"cast(p.credit_amount * COALESCE(cer.val,1.00) as BIGINT) as credit_amount_usd"
```

I want to cast credit_amount_usd column same as p.credit_amount datatype and not BIGINT.

Comment: You probably need to use Python/Scala for this

Answer (score 0):

Example in scala , spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Sale(
                 corp:    String,
                 product: String,
                 data:    Long,
                 group:   String,
                 sales:   Long,
                 market:  String
               )

val df = Seq(
  Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "A", 100, "I"),
  Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "B", 100, "I"),
  Sale("A", "Sut", 43831, "A", 80, "I"),
  Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "C", 50, "C or D"),
  Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "D", 50, "C or D"),
  Sale("B", "Konkurent2", 43831, "C", 40, "C or D")
).toDF().withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

// get type column.
// in our example column name = "sales"
val typeCol = df.dtypes.toMap.getOrElse("sales", "") match {
  case "LongType" => "long"
    // ...
  case _ => "string"
}

val df1 = df
  .withColumn("c0", (col("sales") * 0.25))
  .withColumn("c1", (col("sales") * 10.25).cast(typeCol))

df1.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- corp: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- product: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- data: long (nullable = false)
//  |-- group: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- sales: long (nullable = false)
//  |-- market: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- id: long (nullable = false)
//  |-- c0: double (nullable = false)
//  |-- c1: long (nullable = true)

df1.show(false)
//  +----+----------+-----+-----+-----+------+---+----+----+
//  |corp|product   |data |group|sales|market|id |c0  |c1  |
//  +----+----------+-----+-----+-----+------+---+----+----+
//  |A   |Eli       |43831|A    |100  |I     |0  |25.0|1025|
//  |A   |Eli       |43831|B    |100  |I     |1  |25.0|1025|
//  |A   |Sut       |43831|A    |80   |I     |2  |20.0|820 |
//  |A   |Api       |43831|C    |50   |C or D|3  |12.5|512 |
//  |A   |Api       |43831|D    |50   |C or D|4  |12.5|512 |
//  |B   |Konkurent2|43831|C    |40   |C or D|5  |10.0|410 |
//  +----+----------+-----+-----+-----+------+---+----+----+

// when Select 
val df3 = df.select(('sales * 10.25).cast(typeCol).as("newColSales"))
df3.printSchema()
//  |-- newColSales: long (nullable = true)
df3.show(false)
//  +-----------+
//  |newColSales|
//  +-----------+
//  |1025       |
//  |1025       |
//  |820        |
//  |512        |
//  |512        |
//  |410        |
//  +-----------+
```